# event loop error with django and asyncio

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, async-await

I have a management command that starts an asyncio loop, but when i call django runserver, then i get:

> RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1'.

(this is on initializaton of my library)

1. Why is django initializing on a dummy thread?
2. Is there a
   correct way to mix django and asyncio?
3. How can I use await with a django
   database call?

Comment: maybe with http requests ?

Comment: This site doesn't work great with multiple questions because it may take multiple answers to address all of them. Maybe prune this into a more focused question with some code that explains what you are trying to do.